# List of default themeid values

Tags: themes, xpages

I would like to change some default parameters using a theme. For instance the collapse/expande image. I could ofcourse change the themeid for every categorized column but it would be best to set these values as default in the theme.

I came acros a post about a list of default themeid's but ofcourse this link is dead. Is there any other way of finding out the default theme id for xpage components?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a list of theme ids for core controls:
http://xpageswiki.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Work_with_themes#themeID+values+for+core+controls

You can use the following code snippet to find the theme id of a control:

```
getComponent("dynamicViewPanel1").getStyleKitFamily()
```